# Adding values to arrays based on other value

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a program where you roll dices, then based on result you can pick some scores (x3, x4, etc.) and need some way to check how many dices for each value has been rolled (there's a total of 5 dices). So basically I need something like 1: 0 times, 2: 2 times, 3: 1 time and so on for every value. The problem is I don't want to write 20 lines of code for each value so I tried to use array, but outcome seems to be random. Below is my code

```java
int[] a = new int[6];


        for(int i = 0; i<dice.size();i++){
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 1){
                a[0]++;
            }
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 2){
                a[1]++;
            }
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 3){
                a[2]++;
            }
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 4){
                a[3]++;
            }
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 5){
                a[4]++;
            }
            if(dice.get(i).getValue() == 6){
                a[5]++;
            }
        }
        for(int i : a ){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
```

the dice value is set here:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            random = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            dice.get(i).setValue(random);
```

For example when I rolled and got dices: 1, 3, 4, 4, 6 the program printed:
0
1
0
1
1
0
 as if there was one 2, one 4 and one 5.

Comment: Note that `a[dice.get(i).getValue()-1]++;` can replace all your `if` statements .

Comment: Your `for(int i : a )` iterates over the _values_ of `a` and you're then using that as the index. Of course your output is wrong. Use `System.out.println(i)` instead  (or, if you want to print the value as well, iterate like you're doing above, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) { System.out.printf("%d got rolled %d times", (i+1), a[i]); }`)

Comment: It says you area new contributor. Have you seen [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) ? Also, I think it would help you get answers if you posted a [mcve]. By the way, why the _javafx_ tag? I see no reference to _JavaFX_ in your question. And purely for academic reasons, _dice_ is actually plural. Singular is _die_. So you can have one _die_ or five _dice_.

Comment: @Marv [newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak) has arrived, I see. OED = Oxford English Dictionary, correct? Point I was trying to make is that _dices_ is not a word.

Comment: In addition to Arnauds comment you could change to an enhanced for loop: `for (Die d : dice) a[d.getValue()-1]++;` (Assuming `Die` is the element type of the list).

Comment: Thanks for help, a[dice.get(i).getValue()-1]++ worked perfectly.

Comment: And sorry for JavaFX tag, I'm writing it in JavaFX and wanted to show some code for this but then decided not to. Thank you for information about die and dice, english is not my native language and good thing I could learn

Answer (score 0):

The first loop can be shortened by simply subtracting 1 from the value to get the index of the array element to increment (Assuming the list elements are of type `Die` here):

```
for (Die d : dice) {
    a[d.getValue()-1]++;
}
```

The second loop is wrong, since you use the value of the array element to retrieve an element from the array. The equivalent non-enhanced for loop is the following one:

```
for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(a[a[index]]);
}
```

The second array access results in a different outcome than the expected one. You need to rewrite the loop to get the expected result:

```
for(int count : a) {
    System.out.println(count);
}
```